# onSpeechStart: undefined in IOS in react-native-community / voice

Tags: ios, react-native, error-handling, ios13, voice-recognition

**onSpeechStart: undefined in IOS in react-native-community/voice**

**but in android work's good**

> "react": "16.11.0",

> "react-native": "0.62.2",

> "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.3",

> IOS:- 13.4.1

```
onSpeechStart = e => {
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
    this.setState({
      started: true,
    });
    try {
      console.log('onSpeechStart try:-', e);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('onSpeechStart error:-', e);
    }
  };
```

[image]

Comment: what u expect there ? usually there is undefined, if you want the results there is onSpeechResults. Check the example https://github.com/react-native-community/voice/blob/master/example/src/VoiceTest.tsx